How do I fix the insertObjectAnnotation errors in my MATLAB app designer code?
I am trying to write a code that scans and image, identifies certain words, and highlights those words. I am using MATLAB's app designer to build this program. When I try to run my code however, I am getting a ton of error messages especially regarding the insertObjectAnnotation I'm using which I believe is a MATLAB specific code.
The first part of my code works. This image is a picture of my current code. Current Code First Part WorksI can upload an image, but when I press the button to inspect an image, I get a bunch of error codes that look like the image below. Error Messages Console Output I have tried debugging to an extent but I am stuck.
